# Why Codesandbox can't render the code and show strange error

Tags: codesandbox

I learn JavaScript and read code at [this Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dashboard-template-wj79s?file=/src/components/Layout/TopNav/TopNav_Notifications.js)

Problem is it gives this error often on some Sandbpxes:

> NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null

It looks like this; What can I do to remove this error?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your project has any .scss, comment it all.
After it works fine, that is a problem of stylesheet.

Check what variable(starting with '$') is wrong or missing.
If you add third party component, check guide line for it.